# The TIME field in ps -ef

Tags: linux, process, ps, administration, top

When I do ps -ef, I see "TIME" field. What does this field mean? From what I understand, this tells the actual CPU time, that the process got (amidst all the context switching). Does the TIME field include the disk read/write time also or only the CPU time?

Answer (score 7):

It's the *execution time* - the time the process actually used the CPU(s), this does not count in the time the process waits for I/O events.